# Take every row as one partition in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, schema, data-modeling, partition

We want to create table in cassandra keyspace and decided to make only one column as primary key (As a result, that column is the partition key with no clustering key).
For example in 'sample' table, only 'id' column is primary key and so every partition has only one row.

```
create table sample(id int primary key, name text);
```

What are the Advantages and Disadvantages when take every row as one partition?

Comment: Can you provide an example table of what you mean? Are you saying like a key value pair or _just_ the partition key?

Comment: The answer is: it depends. It really depends how you want to query your data. Remember that a table in Cassandra serves purpose of a query, not only storage.

Comment: Table schema ( X   varint  PRIMARY KEY, Y  text,  Z  text, F  int) . This is write-intensive table (Writing versus reading is 100 times)

Comment: Before you create the table, you need to work out what the query looks like. Basically, you would want to add clustering columns to make the data unique as Cassandra does an upsert and you might lose some records.